# how to delete only checked checkbox listview item from database?

Tags: android, checkbox

i have a listview with checkbox in each rows.
i'm using custom cursoradapter and a Array variable for saving checkbox status.

everything is fine.

now i'm trying to delete all checked rows.
but i have no idea how to deal with this.

i know which checkbox is checked. i can save the checked checkbox positions in a new array variable.
but i don't know how to find the database _id by listview position(cursor.getPosition).

is there any way to find the DB _id by listview position(cursor.getPosition)?

or i hope i want to know if there's another way to delete a listview row which is checked in checkbox.

relatvant link or any other comment will be appreciated.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the _id value for a row at a given position via the `CursorAdapter.getItemId(int position)` method. See documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemId%28int%29).